# Importing Spring @Configurations based on System properties

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-annotations

I am trying to migrate our application from Spring XML based configuration to annotation based configuration. In one of our XML files, say `application-config.xml`, we have the following line:

```
<import resource="${jobName}/beans.xml" />
```

Here `${jobName}` is a System property which is set at JVM startup. There are additional system properties that are used to load additional XML resources. Now in my annotation based configuration, I want to have similar `@Configuration` classes as the XML files themselves. Hence I have a class `ApplicationConfig` that will import the `jobName` specific `Configuration` class.

How do I achieve this?

```
@Configuration
@Import({somehow-need-to-use-system-property-to-import-appropriate-class})
class ApplicationConfiguration {
    //bean definitions
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@Import is used to import other Configuration classes into the spring context.

Use @ImportResource to import an xml file.

Since spring 3.1 spring supports system properties in @Import.

I did not check for @ImportResource, but it should be possible as well.

Comment: I don't want to keep any of my XML files. What I want is to migrate all my beans into annotation configurations and import them in the same way as I currently do.